# Adding hyphenation to Core Text?

Tags: objective-c, core-text, core-foundation

I am trying to add hyphenation to a string to draw with Core Text. So far I've found [this category extension on NSString](http://blog.tupil.com/adding-hyphenation-to-nsstring/) that attempts to add hyphens, but it is outdated, and doesn't work when the string has apostrophes, as well as many other issues. And then this [other guy](http://frankzblog.appspot.com/?p=7001) uses that code to do this, but this is dependent on the first source code, which is no good.

But now in iOS 5 there is apparently a built in method for hyphenation, though tutorials and examples are extremely scarce: `CFStringGetHyphenationLocationBeforeIndex`. Can anyone more experienced with Core Text and CF cook up a quick example of how I could potentially use this function?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue right now... I don't know why, but I can't get CFStringGetHyphenationLocationBeforeIndex to work, it always returns NSNotFound. Is it OS X only?? So I'm thinking about using that old NSString category...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, for the category to work, you just need to use `[token length]` instead of  `strlen(tokenChars)` (row 112). `CFStringGetHyphenationLocationBeforeIndex` simply replaces some of the core here http://frankzblog.appspot.com/?p=7001
This method really works if you have simple CTFrameRef's (with CGPath as a rectangle).